# How to read UTM tags and redirect url in react

Tags: html, reactjs, react-native, react-router

I have an URL with UTM tags as below. When a user clicks/ hits the below URL(source), I would like to read UTM tags and redirect to another url(target).

Does anyone have a documentation link to read UTM tags and redirect the url in react?

Example:

**Source**

https://www.CustomDomain.com/?utm_source=linkedin&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=sale&utm_id=123&utm_term=job&utm_content=ad

**Target**

https://www.CustomDomain.com/dashbord

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you need to redirect to page based on UTM values, but the target page can change depending on the UTMs?

Comment: I just need to read UTM tags, store in local storage and redirect to dashboard always

Answer (score 0):

With the latest `react-router-dom` `*v6*`, you can use a new hook named `useSearchParams`. Use it to get query params and you can then store them into `localStorage`,:

```
const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();
searchParams.get("utm_source"); // similar for the rest of query params
```

With ***React router v4***, You need to use `this.props.location.search` for generic or `this.props.location` (with useLocation) for functional components and parse the query parameters either by yourself or using a package